# wrong url in php codeigniter

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to use rest api,I am using following code but when i check in postman then not working for me showimg me following error

```
" Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Api::() "
```

in postman i used -  http://localhost/wordbells/Api/Register

Here is my code

```
<?php 

include 'dp.php';
Class Api extends Db{

    public $response;
    public $_url = "http://localhost/wordbells/";

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->response = new stdClass();
    }

    function Register(){
                    echo "any text here";
    }
}

$url = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '' ;
unset($_POST['action']);
$api = new Api();
//@checking if the method exists or not
if(method_exists($api, $url)):
    $api->$url();
else:
   $api->response->status = false;
   $api->response->message = 'Wrong Url';
   die(json_encode($api->response));
endif;
```

Comment: what does this have to do with codeigniter?

Comment: @Alex  forget codeigniter for now , please tell me how can i solve this problem

Comment: well your error doesn't make sense. it is saying you are calling a blank function, it would make sense if you didn't have this line `method_exists($api, $url)`. frankly i don't see how it is possible with this code only.

Comment: @Alex: showing nothing but status 200 ok

Comment: so you've changed nothing in your code and your error disappears?

Comment: @Alex: actually as you said i removed method_exist line but how can i use any function ? atleast print some text  ?

Comment: no i said your error would make sense *if* that line weren't there, as in a null function is called, but as method exists checks to make sure it isn't null and that the method, well, exists, then your error doesn't make sense with that function being present. as you can see, your code works fine in this example: https://pastebin.com/YSdA6eJ8 and I cannot figure out how in your above code `Api::()` is being called with that function being present.

Comment: can you `var_dump($url)` *directly* before `if(method_exists($api, $url)):` and report what you are getting?